# Does $f(x,y)=\|x-y\|$ reach it's minimum on $F\times G$ where $F,G$ are closed?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x,y)=|x-y|$. I proved that if $K$ is compact and $C$ is closed, then $f$ reach it's minimum on $K\times C$, i.e. there is $(a,b)\in K\times C$ s.t. $f(a,b)\leq f(x,y)$ for all $(x,y)\in K\times C$. Now the question is : is this result still true if we suppose $K$ only closed and not compact ?

---

I really have difficulties to answer to this question. The proof of the fact that it reach its minimum on $K\times C$ use the compactness of $K$, so this argument doesn't work if $K$ is not compact. But in the other hand, all draw I do seem to confirm that if $K$ is just closed but not compact, it still work. For example, if $C\cap K\neq\varnothing $, then it's minimum will be $0$. So, how can I prove the claim ? $ What do you think ?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $F$ and $G$ are supposed to be subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Whoops, missed that, yes.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: thank you. Indeed, they should be in $\mathbb R$, but it's nice to see a more general example :)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: By the way, does such a counter example exist in $\mathbb R$ if we add the fact that $F$ and $G$ must be connected ?

Comment: The only connected closed sets in $\mathbb R$ are closed intervals $[a,b]$ and the infinite closed intervals $[a,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,a],$  and the whole set, $\mathbb R.$ So you can eliminate these cases one at a time. @user659895 the the answer is no.

Answer (score 4):

What about $$F=\mathbb N\quad \text{and}\quad K=\left\{n+\frac{1}{n}\mid n\in\mathbb N, n\geq 2\right\}\ \ ?$$

Comment: You might want to exclude $1+\frac{1}{1}$ from $K$.

Comment: @kccu: Yes, I just did it :-) Thank you.

Comment: Very nice answer, I would never have think to this. Thank you very much.